# sympy solve() unable to find solution

Tags: python, python-2.7, sympy

I have a fairly basic code right now that's supposed to solve the equation shown below but it's not converging to a solution. It just hangs on a pulsing "_"

```
from sympy import *

gamma = 1.4
M_a = 1.0

y = Symbol('y', real=True) 
eqn = Eq((1.0/((gamma/2.0)*(y**2.0))) * ((((1.0 + ((gamma - 1.0)/2.0)*(y**2.0))/(1.0 + ((gamma - 1.0)/2.0)*(M_a**2.0)))**(gamma/(gamma - 1.0))) - 1.0) ,(-0.5704/((1.0 - (y**2.0))**(1.0/2.0))))
print solve(eqn, y)
```

simply printing the equation yields

```
1.42857142857143*y**(-2.0)*((0.166666666666667*y**2.0 + 0.833333333333333)**3.5- 1.0) == -0.5704*(-y**2.0 + 1.0)**(-0.5)
```

which when plugged into wolfram or maple yields the correct solution. ~= 0.696256

So I'm trying to figure out why sympy is unable to solve the equation.

The equation should look like this [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ttobk.png)

If sympy can not be used to solve this equation what can I use instead?

Thanks

Phil

Comment: What happens instead? Any errors?

Comment: nothing happens at all. I think it gets stuck solving it so all I get is a pulsing "_"

I don't think the equation is too complex, so I'm at a loss.

Comment: Maybe non-integer powers?

Answer (score 4):

If you only care about numeric solutions, don't use `solve`. It is trying really hard to find a symbolic solution. But symbolic solutions to polynomials can often be quite complicated, and in general they do not exist.

If you just want a numeric solution, use `nsolve`:

```
In [60]: nsolve(eqn, 0)
Out[60]: mpc(real='0.69625557901731519', imag='-3.4211388289180104e-49')
```

(the 0 is a guess for the solution). The imaginary part there is small enough to ignore. You can remove it with `N(solution, chop=True)`.

If you do care about symbolic solutions, another piece of advice is to avoid floating point exponents. Use rational or integer exponents. In order to find the roots of a polynomial symbolically, it must first be converted to an actual polynomial, i.e., with integer coefficients. This means that floating point coefficients must be converted to rational numbers. But this can often result in huge numbers, and hence very large degrees (this I suspect is why this ends up hanging for you, consider:

```
In [61]: gamma
Out[61]: 1.4

In [62]: Rational(gamma)
Out[62]:
3152519739159347
────────────────
2251799813685248
```

Comment: By the way, another difference here is that `solve` tries to find all solutions, whereas `nsolve` only gives one.